# Is there any way to open downloaded play store app on Android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Greeting all,
Can I open play store app from Android studio after being decompilation for learning but still I can't , if there's any way , pls advice me. Thanks

Comment: You can get the apk of the app then browse the app. But most app are obfuscated. So you won't learn anything. Trying to mess with obfuscate app are more to hack app, not to learn. Better to get some open source app available on git.

Comment: Thanks Teddy Smith